# Open website as an application

Tags: firefox, whatsapp

I want to create a shortcut to Whatsapp web that will open it in Firefox as if it were a standalone application. Ideally: No tabs, address, or extentions visible. Indexed as an application when using alt-tab. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: do you have whatsapp installed already? can you launch it via the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has an extension for a tabless, no-address-shown window, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/popup-window/

After installing that, install another extension,  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-app-mode/